# Powershell bloatware removal script for all users

Tags: windows, powershell, appx

Whenever I install Windows 10/11, I run a PS script to remove some default bloatware.

```
$bloatware = @(
    "ActiproSoftwareLLC"
    "AdobeSystemsIncorporated.AdobePhotoshopExpress"
    "BingNews"
    "BubbleWitch3Saga"
    "CandyCrush"
    "Duolingo"
    "EclipseManager"
    "Facebook"
    "Flipboard"
    "GetHelp"
    "Getstarted"
    "Messaging"
    "Microsoft3DViewer"
    "MicrosoftOfficeHub"
    "MicrosoftSolitaireCollection"
    "Minecraft"
    "MixedReality"
    "News"
    "Office.Lens"
    "Office.OneNote"
    "Office.Sway"
    "Office.Todo.List"
    "OneConnect"
    "PandoraMediaInc"
    "Microsoft.People"
    "Print3D"
    "Royal Revolt"
    "SkypeApp"
    "Speed Test"
    "Spotify"
    "Sway"
    "Twitter"
    "Wallet"
    "Weather"
    "Whiteboard"
    "windowscommunicationsapps"
    "WindowsFeedbackHub"
    "WindowsMaps"
    "Wunderlist"
    "Xbox.TCUI"
    "XboxApp"
    "XboxGameOverlay"
    "XboxIdentityProvider"
    "XboxSpeechToTextOverlay"
    "YourPhone"
    "ZuneMusic"
    "ZuneVideo"
    )

foreach ($bloat in $bloatware) {
    Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name *$bloat* | Remove-AppxPackage
}
```

The script runs with no issues, but if I create another local user for the machine, the same apps are reinstalled to the new user even though I used the *`-AllUsers`* parameter.

How can I prevent those apps from being installed when a user is created?

Comment: You will need to load and install this in the default user hive (`Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT`), see e.g.: [How can I configure default settings for new users?](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/how-can-i-configure-default-settings-new-users)